Trying to initialize TinaCMS
I keep on getting this error when trying to run this command: npx @tinacms/cli@latest init
I am following this tutorial: text
Error
I have done the following already and NONE of these have worked:

Reinstalled Node Modules
Removed the node modules directory
Cleared the npm cache
Used Yarn to try to install TinaCMS (this also doesn't work)
Tried deleting the npm folder in C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming

If anyone has had experience with this and knows a solution, please let me know.
I have done the following already and NONE of these have worked:

Reinstalled Node Modules
Removed the node modules directory
Cleared the npm cache
Used Yarn to try to install TinaCMS (this also doesn't work)
Tried deleting the npm folder in C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
